# How can I real time parse content in a textarea as the user types like how stackoverflow does it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stack-overflow

When adding a post at stackoverflow, I enter text on the edit window, and it appears modified in the display window.  For instance...

- If I type `**Some Text`, I see **Some Text (`**Some Text`)
- If I type `**Some Text*`, I see **Some Text* (`*<em>Some Text</em>`)
- If I type `**Some Text**`, I see **Some Text** (`<strong>Some Text</strong>`)

How do they do this?  Is there a jQuery solution?

Comment: It's a Markdown plugin.  See https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/

Comment: on keydown keypress or input, update a preview div.

Comment: @RobertHarvey.  Like http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/markdown?

Comment: @RobertHarvey.  Thank you, I never heard the term "markdown" below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this syntax for writing in the comments is called Markdown. There are a few javascript Markdown parsers.  https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/ for example

Answer (score 1):

It's just the effect of `keyup` event.

You can listen the event and, when it occurs, use a callback  to process the text and show the visualization of it after the processing.

Something similar can be created with this library: http://epiceditor.com/ - Specially in fullscreen.